# Автокомплит для поисковой ячейки (CSS)

Tags: css

Я написал код, который при отжатии кнопки делает запрос к БД и достаёт из нёё товары со схожими с значением инпута именами, нужно чтобы ответы выдавались под поисковой ячейкой в виде белых полосок (так собственно и должен выглядеть автокомплит). Как этого добиться с помощью CSS?
Ответ из базы данных приходит в виде `<ul><li>Ответ 1</li><li>Ответ 2</li></ul>`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

ну и засуньте список под инпут.

```css
.search {
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.response {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  border-style: none solid solid;
  border-color: #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

.response li {
  padding: 0.15em 0.75em;
}
```

```html
<input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search here..."></input> <button class="search">Search</button><br>
<ul class="response">
  <li id="result1">result1</li>
  <li id="result2">result2</li>
  <li id="result3">result3</li>
  <li id="result4">result4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Если минусите, напишите, плиз, что не понравилось.